# Python 3: Using OOP to change Class to Integer on Conditional Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Apologies for incorrect lingo, I am still new to this.

I want to make a class initialiser that, using a conditional, will decide whether or not the instance of said class will collapse into a simple integer.

Simplified Unworking Example:

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        if self.b == 0:
            return int(a)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(a)+":"+str(b)

DoesntBecomeAnInt = A(3,4)
WillBecomeAnInt = A(3,0)
print(DoesntBecomeAnInt,WillBecomeAnInt)

##Desired Output:
##3:4, 3
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if b == 0:
            return a
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print('Initilizing')
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.a)+":"+str(self.b)
```

[`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is the method used to control the creation of new objects (hence the name).  Here we check if `b` is zero in `__new__` and return an instance of the appropriate type.

In action:

```
>>> DoesntBecomeAnInt = A(3,4)
Initilizing
>>> WillBecomeAnInt = A(3,0)
>>> print(DoesntBecomeAnInt,WillBecomeAnInt)
3:4 3
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: This is bizarre and makes understanding the behavior of callers more difficult. -1

Answer (score 2):

You should use the magic method `__new__` for this. `__new__` is used as a factory where you can decide which class should be instantiated.

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(self, a):
        return int(a)

A(4)
> 4
A(4).__class__
> <type 'int'>
```

Comment: `__new__` needs to take `b` as well here

Comment: This is bizarre and makes understanding the behavior of callers more difficult. -1

Answer (score 1):

## You don't.

The behavior you desire is completely unexpected and somewhat bizarre. Calling `A()` is expected to return an instance of `A`. Doing anything else is confusing and unintuitive, which makes it difficult to read and understand any code invoking it.

## Alternative

If you really need this behavior, create a factory method:

```
def make_thing(a, b):
    if 0 == b:
        return int(a)
    else:
        return A(a, b)
```

Obviously, you need a better name than `make_thing`, but without any context, I can't give you any suggestions.

## Avoid the problem if possible

Since `A` is not a number and is generally not compatible with `int`, it is also somewhat strange to store both `int` and `A` in the same variable.

If all you're doing is converting to a string, then you don't need a class at all. A simple method outside of a class is the better alternative:

```
def a_and_b_to_string(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return str(int(a))
    else:
        return str(a) + ":" + str(b)
```

If you're doing more than that, your calling code will probably end up looking something like this:

```
x = make_thing(input1, input2)
if isinstance(x, A):
    result = x.some_method_from_a() # Or some other calculation requiring an A
else:
    result = 5 * x # Or some other calculation requiring an `int`
```

This is somewhat silly: you write a method to choose the data type and then have to write specialized code for each possible result. You're not getting any benefits from having a function that returns the separate types here. I can think of two simpler alternatives:

1. Just move the check to the calling code:

   ```
   if input2 == 0:
       temp = A(input1, input2)
       result = temp.some_method_from_a() # Or some other calculation requiring an A
   else:
       result = 5 * int(input1) # Or some other calculation requiring an int
   ```

   If you go this route, you should also modify `A.__init__` to throw a `ValueError` if `b == 0`, since that would be an invalid state for an `A` to be in.
2. Modify `A` so that it works properly regardless of whether `b` is `0`:

   ```
   class A(object):
       def __init__(self,a,b):
           self.a = a
           self.b = b

       def some_method_from_a():
           if self.b == 0:
               # Some calculation involving only a
               return int(self.a) * 5
           else:
               # Some other more complex calculation involving both a and b
               return self.a * self.b * 6

       def __repr__(self):
           if self.b == 0:
               return str(int(self.a))
           else:
               return str(self.a) + ":" + str(self.b)
   ```

   Then

   ```
   x = A(a, b)
   result = x.some_method_from_a()
   ```

But again, it's hard to provide recommendations without knowing how you're actually using it.

Answer (score 1):

Using dataclasses

```
# A(...) should either raise an exception or 
# return an instance of A to avoid confusion. 
# create can do whatever you want it to.

import dataclasses 

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    print('Initializing')
    a : int
    b : int
               
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.b == 0:
            return str(int(self.a))
        else:
            return str(self.a) + ":" + str(self.b)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, a, b):
        if b == 0:
            return a
        return cls(a, b)

DoesntBecomeAnInt = A.create(3,4)
WillBecomeAnInt = A.create(3,0)
print(f'{DoesntBecomeAnInt}\n{WillBecomeAnInt}')
```

```
Initializing
3:4
3

[Program finished]
```